# Bash script in ( set -x ) mode does not display what "cat" command does. ( contents of it )

Tags: bash, shell-script, debugging

in this bash script.. it simply shows..

```
    +cat
```

as it runs.

```
#!/bin/bash
set -x
cat > /test << "EOF"
a
b
c
d
EOF
```

but i rather show everything that it does . including the

```
a
b
c
d
```

that it adds to a file.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try using `set -v` instead of the `set -x`

Answer (score 2):

This occurs because `set -x` displays the evaluation of expansions - which is not a factor regarding typical redirections.

```
LC_ALL=C man set |
sed -n '/^ *-x/,/^$/p'

   -x    The  shell  shall  write  to standard error a
         trace for each command after it  expands  the
         command  and  before  it  executes  it. It is
         unspecified whether the  command  that  turns
         tracing off is traced.
```

From the [POSIX spec](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009604599/utilities/xcu_chap02.html#tag_02_07_04)

> The redirection operators `<<` and `<<-` both allow redirection of lines contained in a shell input file, known as a *here-document*, to the input of a command.

It is `cat` that receives that input - not the shell. So there is no *expansion* for it to report on before execution. And, after it has handed that bit of its input off, there's really no data for it to report on anyway.

This is why - as is recommended elsewhere `set -v` does work whereas `-x` does not:

```
LC_ALL=C man set |
sed -n '/^ *-v/,/^$/p'

   -v    The shell shall write its input  to  standard
         error as it is read.
```

In that case it duplicates its input to `stderr` while reading it - before redirections - whether it expands it or not.

Answer (score 1):

There’s no functionality in the shell to support this. 
You could achieve this *specific* result by doing

```
tee /test << "EOF"
a
b
c
d
EOF
```

but this is not trivially adaptable to everything you could do in a shell script.

You might want to look into programs like `screen` and `Expect`.